# What are these question marks in my Android logfile?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Can someone please tell me what this means:

```
07-04 09:54:38.048: I/DetailActivity(15496): Title that is set : ��Le
```

I got this from a log file for an android app that I am writing. This is in a String variable and the data comes from a Parcable method that I used to pass data from one activity to another. Please let me know if you need the code, but I'm hoping someone can explain what they are rather than w

Comment: Probably UTF-8 or UTF-16 characters observed in an editor or terminal that doesn't know they're UTF.

Comment: Probably `Windows-1252` characters in the range 0x80 .. 0xBFF shown/interpreted as `UTF-8`. One can take the log file and use for instance JEdit which can reload a text in different encodings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a character encoding issue.  The two characters are represented by a series of bits in your app (probably UTF-8) that do not translate to ASCII.

Read Joel on Software's [blog post on the subject](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Awesome article. May have applied to my situation, indirectly, so to speak. That's enough for me to upvote and accept :) Thanks!